# Difference between using camel cxfrs and jaxrs server

Tags: jax-rs, apache-camel

xmlns:cxfrs="http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf"

xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"

I am trying to understand the cxfrs:server and JAXRS:Server in Apache Camel. How it is different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, these two are used to configure the server.

But cxfrs:server is used to configure the server which is used by the camel-cxfrs to route the REST request to camel route, it doesn't invoke the resources classes instance method; jaxrs:server is used to expose the REST service which can accept the REST request and send response by invoke  the resources classes instance that you configured.

Comment: Hi Willem, I'm still trying to understand the difference between these two. You mentioned that jaxrs:server is used to expose the REST services so that the methods inside the service classes can be called. However, I used the CXF-RS component by only configuring a jaxrs:server, and it did not invoke the methods inside the service classes. So, I'm still confused about the differences between these two..

Comment: Did you get the response from the CXFRS server? How can you tell the method in the service classes is not called ?

Comment: Yes, I'll ask this in a separate question so I can explain my question better.